# C++ Win32: HDC's, HWND's, SelectObject, and GetObject

Tags: winapi, select, get, hwnd, gdi

I'm new to win32 and there are some concepts I haven't fully grasped. For one, the difference between HDC and HWND. I understand (or think I understand) that they're handles to a objects and that hdc's can be derived from hwnd's. Like in the case of BeginPaint:

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

But i don't fully understand what seperates each as certain methods have hdc as parameters and some use hwnd

Secondly, I'm not sure what SelectObject and GetObject do. I think that they associate handles with various objects, like in the case of this bitmap drawing function:

```
BOOL DrawBitmap (HDC hDC, INT x, INT y, INT width, INT height, HBITMAP hBitmap, 
                 DWORD dwROP)
{
    HDC       hDCBits;
    BITMAP    Bitmap;
    BOOL      bResult;

    hDCBits = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR)&Bitmap);
    SelectObject(hDCBits, hBitmap);
    bResult = StretchBlt(hDC, x, y, width, height,hDCBits, 0, 0, Bitmap.bmWidth,
                         Bitmap.bmHeight, dwROP);
    DeleteDC(hDCBits);

    return bResult;
}
```

But despite all of this I don't understand exactly what they do or how they work. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Start by reading the reference documentation: [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595.aspx) and [Device Contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183553.aspx).

Comment: HWNDs represent windows, HDCs represent device contexts that let you paint to a window (but also to printers). Sounds like you need a book for beginners; [Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) is the gold standard.